# Rotation and Translation of coordinate system

Tags: matrices, rotations

[image: pic]

Let subscript r indicate in red coordinate, subscript b indicate in blue coordinate.

as the image above, the $Z_r$ axis is parallel to  $Y_b$ axis, $X_r$ is parallel to $X_b$, and $Y_r$ is parallel to $Z_b$ but direction is opposite.

The origin of the red coordinate shifts **t** on the $Z_b$ axis relative to the blue one.

For a same point (x, y, z), what is the relation between (**$x_b$**, **$y_b$**, **$z_b$**) and (**$x_r$**, **$y_r$**, **$z_r$**)?

Actually, I realize that the the red coordinate system rotates 90 degrees  count clockwise around the X axis of the blue coordinate system.

So in my mind, the $R$ matrix is $\begin{Bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{Bmatrix}
$
and the T matrix is $\begin{Bmatrix}0 & 0 & t \end{Bmatrix}$

For a same point (x, y, z) in space

$\begin{Bmatrix}
    x_r \\ 
    y_r \\ 
    z_r \\ 
    1 \\
\end{Bmatrix}$
 = 
$\begin{Bmatrix}
 R & T \\
 0^T & 1 \\
\end{Bmatrix}
$
$\begin{Bmatrix}
    x_b \\ 
    y_b \\ 
    z_b \\ 
    1 \\
\end{Bmatrix}$

But, the result is not what I want.
So what is wrong?

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Please explain your work on this so far, and precisely where you got stuck.

Comment: [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803/265466)